# Having a Custom ListView with a spinner and checkbox Implemented

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, spinner

All I'm looking to do, is have a ListView with a textView and ***EITHER*** a spinner on the right side or a check box.
I'm having so much difficulty with this it's ridiculous. Can anyone help me please? :(.

Here's what i have so far that implements a spinner by itself. (I created R.array for planets. so it does work.)

```
public class AlarmOptions extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        Spinner mySpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
```

Here is the XML file main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:text="Please select a planet:"
/>

<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
/>
<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt1"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

PLEASE HELP :'(

Comment: This search should help you , the question has been answered a couple of times :-) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+listview+checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is: Create a list view like normal. Then create a separate xml file with the layout your would like for *each* item in the list view. This would work for both the spinner and the checkbox and is simple and easy to create.

Please consider:

```
<...xml header stuff .../>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Spinner (or Checkbox) android:id="@+id/spinny"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+is/texty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then for your activity you would create a ListView just like you normally would. inflating this layout for each ListView item in the `getView(...args...)` method of the ListView adapter.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around it... Ultimately I want to duplicate what android did for an generic alarm app that comes standard on every android phone. 
It has a set of options in a listView with some having checkBoxes and some spinners. 
Would I have to create the xml for each row view from scratch and then set onClickListeners for the spinners and checkBoxes?? I really appreciate the help, btw.

Comment: ok, It's starting to make more sense. Lemme give it a try and I'll let you know how it goes :D

Comment: Hey man, Still new on here. Is there a way I can PM you? 
Currently I'm trying this and its only populating the listView with a textview and not the spinner like I want it to. AM I inflating it wrong? Can't show you my code in this small reply box.

Comment: @cj1098 - Hey sorry, I can't devote that kinda time right now. At work and all. You need to add data to the spinner in the `getView()` method, and you will need to do it to every spinner. I recommend using the check box. It will be simpler and requires less content.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1482/discussion-between-cj1098-and-aedonetlira)